# Formula Specific to Running User?

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, user

I have a requirement where a certain field can be edited without the validations firing for a particular user. Now I tried to write rule like `LastModifiedId != '005000000000000AAA'` but the validation was still firing. Then I realized that until the record saves, the `LastModifiedId` does not change and the validations still fire, as the `LastModifiedId` would not be updated to the exempted `User`.

Is there any workaround or a way to check the Id of the User who is *currently editing* the record?

Comment: For example, you can use $User.id -  https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h3IlAAI

Comment: possible duplicate of [allow user in validation rule](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40266/excluding-certain-user-from-validation-rule)

Comment: @TusharSharma Custom Permissions are a far preferable approach.

Comment: This does look like a duplicate question, but I'll vote to keep this open because the answer here is more comprehensive and up to date.

Comment: Since the answer can be applied to merge fields *anywhere*, I edited the title to be more generally applicable (and hopefully more searchable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few approaches you can take here, which I will list in order of preference. These should work just about anywhere merge fields can be used.

---

**Create a Custom Permission**

You can check if someone has a `Custom Permission` in a formula as follows:

```
$Permission.My_Custom_Permission__c
```

Steps:

1. Create `Custom Permission`
2. Add it to a `Permission Set`
3. Assign that `Permission Set` to any `User` you wish to exempt from validation

---

**Hierarchy Custom Setting**

If you don't find the above palatable for some reason, you can also check a `Hierarchy Custom Setting` in a formula as follows:

```
$My_Hierarchy_Setting__c.Is_Exempt_From_Validation_X__c
```

Steps:

1. Create `Hierarchy Custom Setting`
2. Add exemption field
3. Set `Org Wide Default` for this field to false
4. Set value to true for any `User` you wish to exempt from validation

---

**Alias**

You can check against an `Alias` in a way that in all environments as follows:

```
$User.Alias = "analias"
```

---

**Username**

Somewhat less clean than `Alias`, but you would check against a `Username` as follows:

```
BEGINS($User.Username, "user@example.com")
```

---

**User Id**

I would not adopt this approach unless you have compelling reasons none of the above are a good fit:

```
$User.Id = "00550000000lxVg"
```

Comment: I've also used `$User.alias` to avoid the BEGINS (your third option)

Comment: @crop1645 Ah very nice alternative. Will amend my answer.

Comment: @AdrianLarson detail solution. +1

Comment: Used the $User.alias method. Worked like a charm, thank you! :)

Comment: Can also use a custom field on user.  No real advantages vs the other methods, but it's an option...

Comment: @gorav I actually find that approach abhorrent and significantly worse than any of the above except hard coding the Id.

Comment: Agree, it is better than hard coding the id.  Before custom permissions, it might have had a use case.  Can't see why it would be needed now, but better than hard coding id.

Comment: One use case is notifications for sensitive permissions.  Since you can't have trigger on custom setting or permission set assignment, using a field on user let's you use a workflow rule to notify when permission granted.    Also allows for easy reporting, if end users need to review all users w said permission.  Still agree it's ugly.