# Logged in user can only edit the record they relate to. Validation Rule

Tags: validation, user, validation-rule

Is there a way to retrieve the current user in a validation rule?

The logged in user will be logging in from a community.

Need to make the record only editable if the Logged in user matches the Look up field on the record.

This is for multiple users. So cannot explicit put the user.id in the rule

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation should not fire for a specific user](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113707/validation-should-not-fire-for-a-specific-user)

Comment: I think what @Yandel wants is to validate the current user based on a user lookup field within an object. So this needs to be dynamic instead of using a single User Id for validation.

Comment: @SeanSoriano exactly what is required.

Comment: @SeanSoriano Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Lookup field is a user, this can easily be done by creating a validation rule that will check for the current user's id and the lookup field's id.

Here's a sample validation rule that compares the records owner(user lookup) with the current user's id. The validation will fire if the User Id is not equal to the owner of the record. Just replace the OwnerId with your own User lookup field.

```
 $User.Id <>  OwnerId
```