# why my workflow is firing even tho I am saying dont

Tags: workflow

I have my work flow with validation rule and eventho I am trying to not fire when those ownerId are submitting it. it still does

```
OR( 
    Owner.Id <> "00516000006OnYB" , 
    Owner.Id <> "005G0000002YHAe" , 
    Owner.Id <> "005G0000005Foy2" , 
    Owner.Id <> "00516000006Tdoh" , 
    Owner.Id <> "005G0000004qehs"
) && 
Order_Paperwork_Complete__c = TRUE
```

Comment: Similar questions have already been asked on SFSE. I have outlined in more detail how to ignore certain users in a formula here: [Validation should not fire for a specific user](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113707/validation-should-not-fire-for-a-specific-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your rule is firing anyways is because your criteria is wrong. OR means that *any* condition will allow the rule to fire, while AND means that all the conditions must be necessary to fire.

Let's walk through an example:

```
OR( 
    Owner.Id <> "00516000006OnYB" , 
    Owner.Id <> "005G0000002YHAe" , 
    Owner.Id <> "005G0000005Foy2" , 
    Owner.Id <> "00516000006Tdoh" , 
    Owner.Id <> "005G0000004qehs"
) && 
Order_Paperwork_Complete__c = TRUE
```

When Owner.Id is 00516000006OnYB:

```
OR(
    FALSE, // It is equal, so Boolean FALSE
    TRUE,  // Is not equal, so Boolean TRUE
    TRUE,  // Ditto...
    TRUE,
    TRUE
) && TRUE
```

`FALSE OR TRUE` evaluates to TRUE, so the rule triggers.

However, if you change the formula to AND:

```
AND(
    FALSE, // It is equal, so Boolean FALSE
    TRUE,  // Is not equal, so Boolean TRUE
    TRUE,  // Ditto...
    TRUE,
    TRUE
) && TRUE
```

`FALSE AND TRUE` is FALSE, so the entire formula eventually evaluates to FALSE, and the rule will not trigger.

Comment: Thank you very much for the respond, it works perfectly now