# Able to display only certain names

Tags: formula

I have requirement where I have a field called Agent's name where I want to display only certain names whosover login, suppose I have names X,Y,Z,A,B,C, and D to be displayed.

Comment: So what have you tried before? Where are you stuck? If you haven't before, please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: I am trying to create a formulae using IF and OR statement but would need help on this

Comment: Please explain your use-case. What is your end goal?

Comment: Certain login agents should only see the names and not all

Comment: [Duplicate](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113707/validation-should-not-fire-for-a-specific-user/113722#113722)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a formula that specifies if the *running user* is in a privileged group, consider `Custom Permissions`. See: [$Permission Global Variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_permission.htm). Your formula would simply look like:

```
$Permission.MyCustomPermission
```

1. Navigate to `Setup` > `Develop` > `Custom Permisions`.
2. Click the <kbd>New</kbd> button.
3. Specify a `Label`.
4. `Name` will auto-populate. Replace `MyCustomPermission` above with that value.
5. Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.
6. Navigate to `Setup` > `Administer` > `Permission Sets`.
7. Click the <kbd>New</kbd> button.
8. Populate `Label`. This `Name` value is not particularly important.
9. Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.
10. Click the <kbd>Manage Assignments</kbd> button.
11. Select `Users` as desired.

Comment: `;` at end of formula ??

Comment: Ha good catch. The way that comment came through on my phone I wasn't sure what you were getting at. Now it makes sense.