# How to not hard-code Exempt User Id?

Tags: opportunity, administration, validation-rule

I'm having some issues with the following validation rule:

```
AND( 
OR(
ISCHANGED(Sales_Rep__c),
ISCHANGED(Secondary_Rep__c)
),

$User.Id<>"005A0000005sOAv", /*User1 */ 
$User.Id<>"005A0000007TTqR" /*User2 */ 

)
```

The intended function is that it is supposed to restrict the editing of either sales rep field, unless you're one of the 2 listed users trying to edit it. If you are one of these two, editing of the field is allowed.

Initial error resolved, was comma.

Issue to be resolved:
Is there a way to reference a user in a validation rule other than by their ID? In Apex I know I can query. How should I go about not hard-coding in a validation rule?

Comment: You don't need coma after `$User.Id<>"005A0000007TTqR", /*User2 */ `. Also, hardcoding Ids is not recommended

Comment: That resolved the issue, thank you. @Oleksiy - How would I go about referencing users in a validation rule without hardcoding an ID?

Comment: Use a custom permission instead.  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221057&language=en_US

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you validate based on the running user, [my previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/113707/2995) applies here as well.

There are a few approaches you can take here, which I will list in order of preference. These should work just about anywhere merge fields can be used.

---

**Create a Custom Permission**

You can check if someone has a `Custom Permission` in a formula as follows:

```
$Permission.My_Custom_Permission__c
```

Steps:

1. Create `Custom Permission`
2. Add it to a `Permission Set`
3. Assign that `Permission Set` to any `User` you wish to exempt from validation

---

**Hierarchy Custom Setting**

If you don't find the above palatable for some reason, you can also check a `Hierarchy Custom Setting` in a formula as follows:

```
$My_Hierarchy_Setting__c.Is_Exempt_From_Validation_X__c
```

Steps:

1. Create `Hierarchy Custom Setting`
2. Add exemption field
3. Set `Org Wide Default` for this field to false
4. Set value to true for any `User` you wish to exempt from validation

---

**Alias**

You can check against an `Alias` in a way that in all environments as follows:

```
$User.Alias = "analias"
```

---

**Username**

Somewhat less clean than `Alias`, but you would check against a `Username` as follows:

```
BEGINS($User.Username, "user@example.com")
```

---

**User Id**

I would not adopt this approach unless you have compelling reasons none of the above are a good fit:

```
$User.Id = "00550000000lxVg"
```

Comment: For whatever reason that other one didn't come up when I was searching for the issue.. odd. Thanks for the information! I went ahead and clicked yes on "Question already answered?" when it popped up, to link out to the other post as well.