# Validation rule against Contact card

Tags: validation, validation-rule, contact

Can someone help me with validation rule against Contact.

We have a contact named 'Anonymous Contact' which we are using in several process builders etc.. and I would like to do a validation rule that no one else can edit that contact card (first name & last name or anything else in the contact card) than System Administrator. And this validation rule should apply only on this particular contact.

Comment: please takse some time to review [ask], have you tried writing one? maybe you can check https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_useful_field_validation_formulas.htm&type=0 and try one before asking someone to do it for you? if you eencounter any troubles, try adding your attempted rule to your question and point out any specific issues you encounmter

Comment: Hi Lauri, welcome to SFSE! In general, we expect you to attempt to solve the problem and then come here with where specifically you got stuck. You might also consider reading other related posts around SFSE such as [Formula Specific to Running User?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113707/2995)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below validation rule : --

```
AND(
      NOT(ISNEW()),
      $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
      FirstName  = "Anonymous",
      LastName = "Contact"
)
```

explanation : -

1. Isnew() is checking whether the record is edit mode or new mode.
2. System Admin can edit the record.
3. Contact Name you can not find so checking the particular Name need to use the firstName and LastName.