# Validation rule for non testing context

Tags: apex, validation, validation-rule

In Apex to separate code execution for test and non-test context we use the following method

```
Test.isRunningTest()
```

Do we have any such thing for validation rules i.e the validation rule should be active only for non-test context and for test-context it should be inactive.

Any hacks/unorthodox tips would be appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a [great many ways](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/113707/2995) to validate for a specific user, and I would say those are most appropriate here as well. Simply check the following in your rule:

```
AND(
    NOT($Permission.SkipOpportunityValidations),
    OtherCriteria
)
```

Then, run your test as a `User` who has this permission assigned. You will need to add the `Custom Permission` to a `Permission Set`, then make sure this context user has it assigned.

```
Id permissionSetId = [
    SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'SkipOpportunityValidations'
].Id;
User contextUser = (User)SObjectFactory.create(User.sObjectType);
PermissionSetAssignment assignment = new PermissionSetAssignemnt(
    PermissionSetId=permissionSetId, AssigneeId=contextUser.Id;
);
system.runAs(contextUser)
{
    // validations will now be skipped
}
```